# Change position of a control in <tr> relative to other controls

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I got this gui:

[image]

but I want this:

[image]

Code for picture nr1:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan ="3">
        <asp:ListBox ID="tr_process_list" runat="server" Rows="10" style="width:180px;" OnInit="tr_process_list_Init" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="addProcess" Text="Add" OnClick="addProcess_Click"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="removeProcess" Text="Remove" OnClick="removeProcess_Click" />
        <asp:ListBox ID="tr_process_selectedlist" runat="server" Rows="10" style="width:180px;" OnInit="tr_process_selectedlist_Init" OnSelectedIndexChanged="tr_process_selectedlist_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:ListBox>
     </td>
</tr>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you have any control over the HTML, such as add another element?

Comment: yes, I think so. All my components are in a table though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the HTML, add a wrapping element around the buttons and try the following CSS.

The trick is to add a wrapping element that is an inline-block.  Within the inline-block, you can use `display: block` on the buttons with margin left/right auto to center them.

You can specify a width or padding to style the white space as needed.

If your `textarea` elements are tall enough, you can vertically center the labels by specifying `vertical-align: middle` to the two `textarea` elements and the `.inline-panel` element.

```css
/* Example for large text area panels */
td { 
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
td textarea {
  height: 200px; /* for example */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inline-panel {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 8em; /* optional */
  padding-bottom: 0em; /* optional */
}
.inline-panel button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto; /*left right values of auto for centering */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <div class="inline-panel">
        <button>View</button>
        <button>Reset</button>
      </div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, But what if my "textarea"'s are that big so the inline-panel comes at the button of the tr and not in the center. How to fix that?

Comment: I modified the example to demonstrate one way of keeping the labels vertically centered for tall `textarea`'s.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you divide your row into 3?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:ListBox ID="tr_process_list" runat="server" Rows="10" style="width:180px;" OnInit="tr_process_list_Init" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        </asp:ListBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="addProcess" Text="Add" OnClick="addProcess_Click"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="removeProcess" Text="Remove" OnClick="removeProcess_Click" style="clear:both;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:ListBox ID="tr_process_selectedlist" runat="server" Rows="10" style="width:180px;" OnInit="tr_process_selectedlist_Init" OnSelectedIndexChanged="tr_process_selectedlist_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:ListBox>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How will this guarantee that the two buttons stack vertically?

Comment: You are assuming that the buttons are floated... they may not be.

Comment: yeah you are right, the thing is applying css to those buttons is a must to achieve what op wants. my point is, it is obvious there are 3 divisions on that row, so why now divide it? :)

Comment: There may be other reasons why the OP is using a single table cell to group those elements, maybe it has to do with the flexibility of the design, we can't tell.  However, in your example, how would you get the buttons to stack vertically, assuming they are in a table-cell by themselves?

Comment: add style to 2nd button `style="display:block;"`

Comment: @Emre I'm not splitting the button and listboxes in separate <td>s because I've dynamic listboxes. I don't want empty space when one is disabled.